# Time complexity for consecutive executions

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

I have 3 algorithms (A1, A2 and A3) and their estimated time complexities are `O(n Log n)`, `O(K n)` and `O(Q n)` respectively, where K and Q are different parameters of the actions. Then I have a fourth algorithm that runs those 3 algorithms consecutively (each one needs the results of the previous).

I'm confused about how should I estimate the total complexity of the suite of algorithms. As far as I can understand, `O(n Log n)` grows faster than `O(K n)` and `O(Q n)`, therefore the most important part in terms of time consumption will be A1 and probably that will be the most relevant behavior for a `n` big enough. But that won't reflect that even after A1 is done, still A2 and A3 will take a lot of time.

So I was wondering, how should I account for that? Is it enough by just saying the complexity is `O(n Log n)`?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/487258/what-is-a-plain-english-explanation-of-big-o-notation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The total time complexity is:

> O(n Log n) + O(K n) + O(Q n)

which if assumed that `K` and `Q` are parameters that grow slower than or similarly to `Log n`, then the total time complexity is:

> O(n Log n)

since we are using big-o notation. Otherwise the total time complexity is the initial sum (or part of it).

---

The idea is to keep the term that will **dominate** the other term(s) when `n` grows.